# How do I write java code, to display the name automatically when after inputting id or number?

Tags: java, php, retrofit

based on the image below, I have NIK & NAMA fields. the concept is when I fill in the NIK field then I press the GET button it will display the name(NAMA FIELD)

[Picture : Menu add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAbMU.png)

Database structure example

| NIK | NAMA |
| --- | --- |
| 96296 | Farrasta |
| 94878 | Alfian |

Java class

```
btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NikKry = etNik.getText().toString();

        getNama(); // THE FUNCTION 

    }
});

private void getNama(){

    APIRequestData armNama = RetroMaster.konekRetrofit().create(APIRequestData.class);
    Call<ResponseMaster> tampilNama = armNama.ardGetNama(NikKry);

    tampilNama.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseMaster>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseMaster> call, Response<ResponseMaster> response) {

            // HOW TO CODE PROPERLY ?

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseMaster> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

PHP file

```
<?php
include ("koneksi.php");
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $NIK = $_POST["NIK"];
    $query = "SELECT NAMA FROM MASTER_KRY WHERE NIK = '$NIK'";
    $eksekusi = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $cek = oci_execute($eksekusi);

    if($cek > 0){
        $response["data"] = array();

        while($ambil = oci_fetch_object($eksekusi)){
            $F["NAMA"] = $ambil->NAMA;
            array_push($response["data"], $F);
        }
    }else{
        $response["pesan"] = "Data tidak tersedia";
    }
}
else{
    $response["pesan"] = "*&*%4668%*%^$%#*&*(()%$!@#%";
}
echo json_encode($response);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: you used edittext or spinner?

Comment: @UrvishShiroya i used edittext

Comment: This might help
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/style#AutoComplete

Answer (score 0):

If you used `EditText` then this method will be help you to notify when text change in EditText.

```java
editTextObject.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // here you get text via "s.toString();"
            NikKry = s.toString();
            getNama();
        }
    });
```

If you used `AutoCompleteTextView` then this method will be help you like:

```java
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        NikKry = yourArrayList.get(position).getText().toString();
        getNama();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
         
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your entity of ResponseMaster. If the entity has field `Nama` and getter setter exists, you can use below:

```
if(response.isSuccessful()){
    edNama.setText(response.body().getNama());
}else{
    // show toast or log error
}
```

Comment: I've changed ResponseMaster to DataMaster that contain entity NAMA and i did getter & setter. after that i used your code but still not work properly

Comment: public class DataMaster {
    private String NIK;
    private String NAMA;
    public String getNIK() {
        return NIK;
    }
    public void setNIK(String NIK) {
        this.NIK = NIK;
    }
    public String getNAMA() {
        return NAMA;
    }
    public void setNAMA(String NAMA) {
        this.NAMA = NAMA;
    }
}

Comment: btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NikKry = etNik.getText().toString();
                getNama();
            }
        });

Comment: private void getNama(){
        APIRequestData armNama = RetroMaster.konekRetrofit().create(APIRequestData.class);
        Call<DataMaster> tampilNama = armNama.ardGetNama(NikKry);
        tampilNama.enqueue(new Callback<DataMaster>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DataMaster> call, Response<DataMaster> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    etNama.setText(response.body().getNAMA());
                }
            }

Comment: did u know what's wrong ?

Comment: is there an error? did u get the response from your PHP server?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalException : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Comment: that's the error